# Colour overlays with transitions using CSS

Tags: html, css, overlay, transition

I've been trying to get coloured overlays with text for when I hover over images. I got the overlay and the text, but can't seem to get the transition. I'm not sure where the code should go, but I've moved it around and it hasn't worked, so I must have another error somewhere. Thanks for your help!

html

```
<div class="portfolio-sample">
<a href="https://www.google.ca/">
    <img src="https://56.media.tumblr.com/4171ae7ff6b1f4aa69a49077cf15914f/tumblr_o47q56HKdW1qkdz1ko1_400.jpg">
        <div class="overlay">
            <span>Text 
                <br>text text
            </span>
        </div>
</a>
```

css

```
.portfolio-sample {
margin: 20px 20px;
float: left; 
display:block;
position:relative;
}

.overlay {
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:none;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
transition: all 0.5s ease; 
}

.portfolio-sample:hover .overlay {
color: #383838; /*grey3*/
font: 3em 'Open Sans', Verdana, sans-serif;
font-weight: 700; 
text-align: center;
display: flex;
justify-content:center;
flex-direction:column;
opacity:0.9;
}
```

Comment: You cant animate the `display:none` property. Use `opacity:0.0` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So something like this?  Just as a rule of thumb, try to place as much CSS as possible in the normal (non transitioned) style rule.  Then only add the rules for what you want to transition in the `:hover` rule.  In this case, all you needed in the `:hover` rule was `opacity:0.9`.

```css
.portfolio-sample {
  margin: 20px 20px;
  float: left; 
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}

.overlay {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease; 
  color: #383838; /*grey3*/
  font: 3em 'Open Sans', Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700; 
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  opacity:0;
}

.portfolio-sample:hover .overlay {
  opacity:0.9;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-sample">
  <a href="https://www.google.ca/">
    <img src="//placehold.it/500">
    <div class="overlay">
      <span>Text 
        <br>text text
      </span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect! I appreciate the tip :)

Answer (score 2):

this is the `animation` you want? btw use the `visibility` so the animation will run.

```css
.portfolio-sample {
margin: 20px 20px;
float: left; 
display:block;
position:relative;
}

.overlay {
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
display:block;
visibility:hidden;
opacity:0;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
transition: all 0.5s ease; 
}

.portfolio-sample:hover .overlay {
  visibility:visible;
color: #383838; /*grey3*/
font: 3em 'Open Sans', Verdana, sans-serif;
font-weight: 700; 
text-align: center;
display: flex;
justify-content:center;
flex-direction:column;
opacity:0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio-sample">
<a href="https://www.google.ca/">
    <img src="https://56.media.tumblr.com/4171ae7ff6b1f4aa69a49077cf15914f/tumblr_o47q56HKdW1qkdz1ko1_400.jpg">
        <div class="overlay">
            <span>Text 
                <br>text text
            </span>
        </div>
</a>
</div>
```